# error C2504: 'IDispatchImpl' : base class undefined

Tags: c++

I'm upgrading a project from VS2008 to VS2013.  I have encountered the following error (along with many others following, but this is the first issue):

```
1>d:\express\ver38\ide\source\aimauto\AimConfiguration.h(12): error C2504: 'IDispatchImpl' : base class undefined
1>d:\express\ver38\ide\source\aimauto\AimConfiguration.h(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
1>d:\express\ver38\ide\source\aimauto\AimConfiguration.h(32): error C3646: 'COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY' : unknown override specifier
1>d:\express\ver38\ide\source\aimauto\AimConfiguration.h(32): error C2259: 'IDispatch' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'HRESULT IUnknown::QueryInterface(const IID &,void **)' : is abstract
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(114) : see declaration of 'IUnknown::QueryInterface'
1>          'ULONG IUnknown::AddRef(void)' : is abstract
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(118) : see declaration of 'IUnknown::AddRef'
1>          'ULONG IUnknown::Release(void)' : is abstract
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\unknwnbase.h(120) : see declaration of 'IUnknown::Release'
1>          'HRESULT IDispatch::GetTypeInfoCount(UINT *)' : is abstract
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\oaidl.h(2187) : see declaration of 'IDispatch::GetTypeInfoCount'
1>          'HRESULT IDispatch::GetTypeInfo(UINT,LCID,ITypeInfo **)' : is abstract
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\oaidl.h(2190) : see declaration of 'IDispatch::GetTypeInfo'
1>          'HRESULT IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames(const IID &,LPOLESTR *,UINT,LCID,DISPID *)' : is abstract
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\oaidl.h(2195) : see declaration of 'IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames'
1>          'HRESULT IDispatch::Invoke(DISPID,const IID &,LCID,WORD,DISPPARAMS *,VARIANT *,EXCEPINFO *,UINT *)' : is abstract
1>          c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\oaidl.h(2202) : see declaration of 'IDispatch::Invoke'
```

The code in the header file AimConfiguration.h is:

```
class aimConfiguration :
    public IDispatchImpl<IaimConfiguration, &IID_IaimConfiguration, &LIBID_aimAutomationLib,AIM_MAJOR_VER,AIM_MINOR_VER>,
    public ISupportErrorInfo,
    public CComObjectRoot,
    public CComCoClass<aimConfiguration,&CLSID_aimConfiguration>
```

atlcom.h is declared in the cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "atlcom.h"
#include "aimAutomation.h"
#include "AimStrings.h"
#include "AimConfiguration.h"
```

I have found references to similar issues when searching, but I have found no solutions.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Most ATL stuff is in the ATL namespace. I believe the generated stdafx.h defines _ATL_NO_AUTOMATIC_NAMESPACE, so you need to either remove that #define or use `using namespace ATL;` (preferred for .cpp files) or explicitly qualify interfaces and stuff with `ATL::` (preferred for header files).

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening.  That line is not in the stdafx.h, and to be sure, the contents of stdafx.h now are: #include <altbase.h> followed by using namespace ATL; I even changed the aimconfiguration.h line to be public ATL::IDispatchImpl<IaimConfiguration, &IID_IaimConfiguration, &LIBID_aimAutomationLib,AIM_MAJOR_VER,AIM_MINOR_VER>,
 public ISupportErrorInfo,
 public CComObjectRoot,
  public CComCoClass<aimConfiguration,&CLSID_aimConfiguration> and I still get the same errror.

Comment: Ah, an added error I didn't notice, the first error now is Error C2039: 'IDispatchImpl' is not a member of 'ATL'

Comment: Not sure what's wrong then. Try moving the `#include <atlcom.h>` line to stdafx.h (and use arrows instead of quotes: `<atlcom.h>` not `"atlcom.h"`), in case you are including aimconfiguration.h in more than one .cpp file.

Comment: Based on your comments, I created a fresh ATL project using VS 2013 and copied the stdafx.h from there to my upgraded project (and commented out the _ATL_NO_AUTOMATIC_NAMESPACE).  This cleared up the IDispatchImpl error.  I still have a couple thousand compile errors, but this is a good start.  Thanks.